# Mysql previous row check

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want result like this image i.e. if previous row id is equal then I want 1 in that place. Can anyone kindly help?

Comment: Share your insert statement, how you inserting data? Check before insert if row with same id exist and get the latest value of second column, increment it and then insert it

Comment: This is just select Query, not insert query

Answer (score 0):

just try something like this

```
set @tmpid =''; select *,(if(@tmpid = `custid`,'1','0')) as tmpstatus, @tmpid:=`custid` from testtable
```

or just create stored procedure for above query and used it.